# Уникальность элементов ComboBox

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

У меня есть `ComboBox`, который заполняется по нажатию кнопки. Одно нажатие - одно заполнение. Мне нужно, чтобы на каждом нажатии шла сверка текущего элемента со всеми предыдущими, чтобы не было повторений. Я решил попробовать сделать такую проверку:

```
for (int i = 0; i < comboBox1->Items->Count; i++)
    if (System::Convert::ToDouble(comboBox1->Items[i]) != x2)
            comboBox1->Items->Add(System::Convert::ToString(x2));
```

Без проверки заполнение идёт на ура, но элементы могут повторяться. Данный код работать отказывается. То есть ошибки при компиляции не выскакивают, но проверка на осуществляется. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно было бы исправить условие, чтобы оно заработало.

Comment: какой-то кошмар, тебе не приходило в голову добавлять значения в вектор и проверять его, а потом уже обновлять/не обновлять интерфейс без этих жутких проверок и кастов в цикле? олсо, за циклы и ифы без фигурных скобок надо руки отрывать

Comment: @strangeqargo Пришло бы, если бы я умел ими пользоваться. Я только начинаю осваивать язык - поэтому пользуюсь тем, что знаю. 
Фигурные скобочки использую только в том случае, если команд больше одной. В остальном не вижу смысла. Возможно, потом исправлюсь.

Comment: @PavelKas придется Вас разочаровать. Вы осваиваете не тот язык, т.е. это не C++, а C++/CLI - поделка от MS для инфраструктуры .Net, для управляемой (managed) среды.

Comment: По коду непонятно, что такое `x2` и где оно устанавливается. Попробуйте привести так называемый [mcve]. А вообще, вероятная проблема в том, что Вы сравниваете числа с плавающей точкой через `!=`.